# Can I revert changes in a simple c# code block (not a Database context)?

Tags: c#, transactions, rollback, transactional

I searched a lot about "Rollback Transactions". I found `TransactionScope()` which was introduced by Entity Framework 5 and `Database.BeginTransaction()` which has functions commit and rollback introduced by Entity Framework 6. So rollback on Database(context) is possible.

I wanna know if it's possible to undo changes in a simple `C#` code.(Make a piece of code transactional) For example in a code block I add items to a list or change a variable value. Then an exception occurs, can we revert(undo) changes? So that my `List` becomes empty and the variable gets its first value?

Comment: Obviously you can manually undo changes in `catch` block... Are you looking for nice way to write such code OR implementation of Undo/Redo OR some other transactional support?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I'm searching for transactional support in c# code.

Comment: No (comment as generally it is not an answer): C# does not have any constructs that directly support transactions. .Net framework have transaction support for DB (as you've mentioned), but not much more. ([Distributed transactions](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+distributed+transaction) require even more code to be written...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for something called software transactional memory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory

There are some implementations around, but AFAIK they struggle with poor performance so I doubt you can you them in the real production code